# Accessing Flask response from JS frontend

Tags: javascript, python, http, flask, post

I am trying to build an asynchronous  file uploader with JS and Flask. So far the process of sending the file from JS to Flask seems to be working fine, but how to get any information from Flask back to JS afterward has been confusing. Specifically, I went to inform JS of the new URL of the uploaded file after upload completes.
Here's what happens on the JS side when a file is uploaded:

```
let send_one_file = function(file) {
        let filename = file.name;
        var formData = new FormData();
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        formData.append('file[]', file);
        request.open('POST', '/upload');
        request.send(formData);
        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (request.readyState === 4)
                if (request.status === 201) {
                 console.log(filename + " success!");
                 console.log('Response',request.response.data);
                }
                else {console.log(filename + " failed!");}
        };
    };
```

In the line `console.log('Response',request.response.data);` I'm trying to get the string from the response object, which is sent from Flask like so:

```
@app.route("/upload", methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    #at the moment nothing actually happens to the "uploaded" file
    files = request.files.getlist("file[]") 
    response_data = {'path': "/files/"+files[0].filename,}
    return Response(response=jsonify(response_data), status=201, mimetype='application/json')
```

JS detects the status of the response perfectly fine, but so far I can't figure out how to get it to read anything else. The request.response.data is "undefined."

Please let me know if I'm going about this entirely wrong. I've never built a web app before.

Comment: I recommend [using `fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead but since you've started with xhr: `console.log(request.responseText)` and you should see the JSON string sent by Flask. Do `const info = JSON.parse(request.responseText);` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseText)) and you should be able to access `info.path` to get the data Flask is sending back.

Comment: @ChrisG, thank you, I will look into it. I suspected that the way I was going about it was probably not ideal, so it's good to know the alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I ended up with.

JS:

```
let send_via_fetch = function (file) {
     let formData = new FormData();
     formData.append('file', file);
     fetch('/upload', {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: formData

     })
             .then(response => response.json())
             .then(result => {
              update_file_list(result['filename'], result['path'])
             })
             .catch(error => {
              console.log('Error:', error);
             })
    };
```

Python:

```
@bp.route('/upload', methods=['PUT'])
@login_required
def upload():
    f = request.files['file']
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    destination = join(current_app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"], str(now.year), str(now.month))
    if not isdir(destination):
        makedirs(destination)
    filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
    path = join(destination, filename)
    f.save(path)
    response_data = jsonify({'path': path, 'filename':filename})
    resp = make_response(response_data, 201)
    return resp
```